# I keep getting java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, exception, serializable

This is the code that I have been trying

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

abstract class Account implements Serializable {
    protected String accountHolderName;
    protected long balance;

    protected ObjectOutputStream accData;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

class Savings extends Account implements Serializable {

    Savings() throws IOException {
        System.out.print("enter your name: ");
        accountHolderName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("enter your balance: ");
        balance = input.nextLong();
        accData = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(accountHolderName + ".bin"));
        accData.writeObject(this);
        accData.close();
    }
}

class Banking implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Savings savobj = new Savings();
    }
}
```

and this is the exception I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream
>               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
>               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
>           at Savings.(Banking.java:22)
>           at Banking.main(Banking.java:30)

I also tried using `savobj.accData.writeObj(savobj)` from `main(`), but I still get the same exception. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only primitives and classes that implement `Serializable` interface can be serialized. `ObjectOutputStream` doesn't implement this interface.

Quick solution: use the `ObjectOutputStream` in the narrowest possible scope, declare it in the method where it's being used, not as a field in the class. Do similar with other utility classes like `Scanner`.

```
abstract class Account implements Serializable {
    protected String accountHolderName;
    protected long balance;

    //protected ObjectOutputStream accData;

    //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

class Savings extends Account implements Serializable {

    Savings() throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter your name: ");
        accountHolderName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("enter your balance: ");
        balance = input.nextLong();
        ObjectOutputStream accData = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(accountHolderName + ".bin"));
        accData.writeObject(this);
        accData.close();
    }
}
```

Another solution may be just marking these fields as `transient` so they won't be serialized/deserialized:

```
abstract class Account implements Serializable {
    protected String accountHolderName;
    protected long balance;

    protected transient ObjectOutputStream accData;

     transient Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Comment: Both suggestions are pretty good, especially narrowing the scope.  In the long run that'd be a better approach as opposed to using `transient`.